# Does CentOS support Condor?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, condor

I plan to make HPC cluster using Condor as middle-ware. Is CentOS a good choice to be the OS I mean does it support condor and is there any tutorial which could be helpful in installation process?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - indeed, condor is even [distributed as RPMs](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/manual/v7.6/3_2Installation.html#SECTION00426000000000000000) for RHEL4, 5, and 6 (which is to say, CentOS 4/5/6, as CentOS is just a rebadged RHEL).  So I guess it would be more fair to say that Condor supports CentOS than vice versa.

A lot of people use RHEL/CentOS for HPC applications; I'm not a big fan myself, as an HPC compute node is not the same as a print server or web server, and having very out of date libraries and compilers can be a PITA.   But the issue isn't as bad (now) for CentOS 6 as it was for CentOS 5.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan actually I plan to install CentOS5 since it has more support and most of the problems that I can face another people may have experience on how to solve it.